# Why is my mob spawner not working - Where should I be idling?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]I made my mob farm at height 200 and the collection area is on 70

There is no mob spawning, so where should I be idling so I get highest mob spawning rates as possible? I attempted to idle at the collection area but no mobs spawned so I presume I need to be closer? What is the maximum distance from the mob spawner that it'll still work?

Comment: Try leaving the world and entering it again.

Comment: Generally a good place is above the spawner.

Comment: And why do you have the collection are so low? 30 blocks is more than enough. 130 is overkill

Comment: I placed collection so low just beacuse I wanted it on the ground so I don't have to climb always so high.

Comment: I think 128 block distance is the absolute maximum range in which a mob can spawn!

Comment: @IlayaRajaS If no player is within 128 blocks of the spawning areas, then any mobs will despawn immediately. I assume no mobs spawn in the first place.

Comment: So that could fix it decrease distance by at least 2 blocks and it could be working.

Answer (score 5):

Your idle area is 130 blocks from the mob spawner, which is just over the 128 block radius from the player outside of which mobs will not spawn:

[image: Mob spawning]

You should move your idle area up to at least level 72 if you want to see any spawns at all, but I'd recommend having the idle area at y level 175 if you want to reduce the number of mobs despawning.

Comment: wow really informative can you tell me where you got this from ?

Comment: @IlayaRajaS From Minecraft wiki. [Link](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Despawning)